# How to query different tables for data in order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to change this code but don't know how to do it.

I need it check for data in this order from these tables
NodeMACAddresses,
MAC_address,
'No Mac Address' if no data was found

Mac addresses from SNMP are stored in a table automatically called NodeMacAddresses but some units dont respond to SNMP so I add them manually to a table called MAC_address that I created. So I need to first check if there is data in NodeMACAddresses then MAC_address then type 'No Mac Address' if both tables contain NULL.

```
select coalesce(max(MAC), 'No Mac Address')
from NodeMACAddresses 
where NodeID = $@nodeid@;
```

Comment: present your schema and try to formulate clearly what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . Here is one method:

```
select coalesce((select max(MAC)
                 from NodeMACAddresses 
                 where NodeID = $@nodeid@
                ),
                (select max(MAC)
                 from MACAddress
                 where NodeID = $@nodeid@
                ),
                'No Mac Address'
               )
```

Comment: Didn't work, I get  MACRO SQL ERROR - Incorrect syntax near '00'  . Code looks like this
```
    $SQL:select coalesce((select max(MAC)
                 from NodeMACAddresses 
                 where NodeID = $@nodeid@
                ),
                (select max(MAC)
                 from ${MAC_Addresses} 
                 where NodeID = $@nodeid@
                ),
                'No Mac Address'
               )
```
I also updated the original question. Sorry If I was unclear.

Comment: @spifa . . . I don't know why you are referring to a table using a macro, but the problem isn't with the query but with the macro preprocessing.

Comment: @spifa, Why do you have MAC_Addresses in ${} and NodeMACAddresses isn't? Also, your post calls it MAC_address, not MAC_Addresses.

Comment: @GreyOrGray NodeMACAddresses is a table created by the software. MAC_Address is a table I created myself and so thats why I have to put it in ${}. Its supposed to be MAC_address, it was a typo.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm putting the code in a message box in html format thats gonna be sent out. I need to start with SQL or else its just gonna be plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You can rank order all the results and then pull the first one.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        NodeId,MAC,Priority,
        RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NodeID ORDER BY Priority DESC) 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT NodeID,MAC, Priority=1 FROM NodeMACAddresses WHERE  NodeID=@NodeID
        UNION 
        SELECT NodeID,MAC, Priority=2 FROM MAC_Address WHERE NodeID=@NodeID
        UNION
        SELECT NodeID=@nodeid, MAC = 'No Mac Address', Priority=3
    )AS A
)AS B
WHERE
    RN=1
```

Or without ranking

```
SELECT
    NodeId=@NodeID,
    MAC=COALESCE(A.MAC,B.MAC,C.MAC)
FROM
(
    SELECT MAC = 'No Mac Address' 
)AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN NodeMACAddresses A ON A.NodeID=@NodeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN MAC_Address B ON B.NodeID=@NodeID
```

Comment: I am not sure the meaning of the max in your original query. If you have multiple MACs per node, if possible, do you want or MAX/MIN?

Comment: I didn't write the Query. Wasen't even sure what max did.

With ranking i get:MACRO SQL ERROR - Must declare the scalar variable "@NodeID".
Must declare the scalar variable "@NodeID".
Must declare the scalar variable "@nodeid".

Without ranking i get: MACRO SQL ERROR - Must declare the scalar variable "@NodeID".
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Just replace @NodeID with a hardcoded value to test. It is synonymous with $@nodeid@